# Provider information using HL7-FHIR standard

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am new to FHIR 
How to create a Provider information (XML) using HL7-FHIR standard ? do we have any xsd reference to create the provider information 
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a Health Provider Directory/Index you can have a look at existing Implementation Guides:

- [Mobile Care Services Discovery](https://wiki.ihe.net/index.php/Mobile_Care_Services_Discovery_(mCSD))
  is a IHE profile which implements a HPD with FHIR
- [Validated Healthcare Directory Implementation Guide](http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/vhdir/2018Jan/index.html)
  is a FHIR Implementation Guide for a Health Directory

If you compare these two you'll see a common approach on how to represent Paracticioners, Organizations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Information about healthcare providers (and anyone acting in their professional capacity including receptionists, taxi drivers, etc.) is shared using the [Practitioner](http://hl7.org/fhir/practitioner.html) resource.  If you do a search on that page, you'll find links to the XML and JSON schemas.